# Can i run a facebook application hosted on localhost

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to run a facebook hosted on localhost?Will other users throughout the world will be able to use that app or the firewall will be blocking facebook from fetching content from my computer when users request for it?

Answer (score 0):

Firewalls don't even get a chance to intercept it.

"localhost" is on a non-routable network by definition of IPv4. I can not reach your home computer by name reliably and "localhost" will always resolve to the local host.

There are some tricks that you can use to make your home machine visible to the outside world, but they are not reliable and I really don't want to use a service that went down because your Angry Birds game crashed your machine.

Comment: i just want to use my local machine because development and testing is much easier using the local machine

Answer (score 0):

In your app's basic settings (https://developers.facebook.com/apps) under Settings->Basic->Select how your app integrates with Facebook...

Use "Site URL:" and "Mobile Site URL:" to hold your production and development URLs. Both sites will be allowed to authenticate. I'm just using Facebook for authentication so I don't need any of the mobile site redirection features. I usually change the "Mobile Site URL:" to my "localhost:12345" site while I'm testing the authentication, and then set it back to normal when I'm done.